# How to add simulation files here

Tags: discussion

I am new to stack exchange. I don't understand how to insert files from my PC to explain about my queries. For example I would like to add ltspice simulation files here to explain.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange doesn't support uploading of arbitrary files only images plus there is an in-line schematic editor. For things like small C code snippets you can include directly in the question but LTspice files tend to be long and not all that readable, so I'd recommend putting on an external site such as  Pastebin and linking as has been done in this question:

[LTSpice showing negative transistor power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149315/ltspice-showing-negative-transistor-power)

Something to note is that linked files should be supplementary so the question still makes sense if the link disappears, so try to include as much information as you can in the question itself such as the circuit and simulation results. That will also help gain answers from people who may not use LTspice  but can spot the likely issue from the other information.